# "Improve Edit" Dialog Layout Broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, suggested-edits

Just tested a bunch of posts with pending edits in Chrome and Firefox and the layout is broken:

[image]

To reproduce, you need to visit the question itself outside of the suggested edit queue. Click the edit link and then the Improve Edit button.

Comment: I can reproduce. I'm not aware of any recent changes that might have caused it, but I'll check with the team.

Comment: It's not just this post, it's all questions with a pending edit, to be clear. there is an inline width of 680px being added to `div.suggested-edit-container div.mainbar-full div#mainbar` that's pushing it just over the limit of allowing the sidebar to fit in unmolested. It should be getting `width: calc(100% - 300px -24px);` from primary.css. Not sure where there 680px inline width is coming from. cc @JonEricson

Comment: I've added it to our internal bug tracker for triage.

Comment: I just went to repro this and it is working fine for me. So it must have been fixed over the past few months. Please let me know if you still see this.